# Automate Deployement of changed files in JBoss without Eclipse

Tags: jboss, jrebel, hotdeploy, dynamic-class-loaders, dcevm

**What my Requirement is:** When doing any sort of modification in my project's file(s), I want those particular files to get redeployed automatically without manually doing rebuild/redeploy/restart. 
That is, I want changes to reflect on my webpage as soon as I change any file and save it. Changed file should automatically be redeployed in server.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Changed standalone.xml file in JBoss for redeploying the app whenever any files gets changed. But this does not fulfill my requirement properly. Also this method generated Out of Memory error many a times.
2. Thought of using JRebel but it is not available for free.
3. Tried using DCE VM, but no help.

Please suggest any alternate as redeploying project manually takes a lot of time. I want to automate this process by deploying only the changed files in the exploded ear. **I don't want to use any IDE.**

Comment: Is the application actually running on your local workstation or a remote server? Is there a reason why you "don't want to use any IDE"?

Comment: JRebel afaik is free for non-commercial projects. And if you're working on a commercial one, then well, measure up how much time you waste waiting for redeploys.